# Error: No ack for postMessage getDelegateOverrides() in PayPal buttons Blazor WASM

Tags: .net-core, blazor, paypal-sandbox, webassembly

I'm using PayPal buttons with JavaScript SDK in my Blazor WASM project. The button loads perfectly on Firefox but not in Chrome and gives this error on the console :

[Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nupEk.png)

Of the two buttons, the second one works fine (Debit or credit card) but not the first one which allows users to login using PayPal. It opens the modal for PayPal login keeps on loading and then closes unexpectedly giving the error I mentioned above.

Trying to make payments using Javacript SDK of PayPal. It should open up a new window popup for PayPal login but keeps on loading and then it was closed abruptly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.